# Unauthenticated and authenticated APIs using Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

I followed the tutorial at https://serverless-stack.com to create an "events" API. The admin creates an event and then can set a property as "published" to allow guests to view those events.

This works well and I have the backend setup. Now I need to create a frontend calendar that fetches all of the `published: true` events. I created a service called `getPublished` that will fetch the published events.

I want to allow guest/unauthenticated access to this service while requiring authentication for all other routes (besides listPublished - but I can figure that out when I get getPublished figured out).

```
service: events-app-api

# Use the serverless-webpack plugin to transpile ES6
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

# serverless-webpack configuration
# Enable auto-packing of external modules
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1

  # 'iamRoleStatements' defines the permission policy for the Lambda function.
  # In this case Lambda functions are granted with permissions to access DynamoDB.
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*"

functions:
  # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in create.js
  # - path: url path is /events
  # - method: POST request
  # - cors: enabled CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for browser cross
  #     domain api call
  # - authorizer: authenticate using the AWS IAM role
  create:
    handler: create.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: events
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  get:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in get.js
    # - path: url path is /events/{id}
    # - method: GET request
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: events/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  getPublic:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in get.js
    # - path: url path is /events/{id}
    # - method: GET request
    handler: getPublic.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: public/events/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  list:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in list.js
    # - path: url path is /events
    # - method: GET request
    handler: list.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: events
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  listPublic:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in list.js
    # - path: url path is /events
    # - method: GET request
    handler: listPublic.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: public/events
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in update.js
    # - path: url path is /events/{id}
    # - method: PUT request
    handler: update.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: events/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

  delete:
    # Defines an HTTP API endpoint that calls the main function in delete.js
    # - path: url path is /events/{id}
    # - method: DELETE request
    handler: delete.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: events/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam

# Create our resources with separate CloudFormation templates
resources:
  # API Gateway Errors
  - ${file(resources/api-gateway-errors.yml)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a service in the serverless framework, you specify its behaviour in the `serverless.yml` file, for example ([from their Get Note chapter](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/add-a-get-note-api.html)):

```
  get:
    handler: get.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: notes/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

The line `authorizer: aws_iam` is what is configuring your lambda function to use an authoriser (in that case, an IAM role).

If you remove this line, you'll deploy a function without an authoriser. Functions without authorisers can be invoked by anyone.

This configuration is specific to each function, and so you can remove the  `authorizer` from one specification, and leave it in for another.

In your case then (and without code I'm just guessing), all you need do is remove the `authorizer` line from the specification for `getPublished`.

Comment: I removed the authorizer and now I get `message: "Missing Authentication Token"`

Comment: OK- that means somewhere in your code you are attempting to use the authorisation response. Can you include your handler code in the question please?

Comment: I made the change directly in API Gateway and it works.